# R factors get numbers from to

Tags: r, factors

I have list of numbers for example 0,1,0,1,2,3,0,5,6,7,5

```
w=factor(data,levels=c(a=0,b=1,2>))
```

In 2> I want to have levels above then 2 but I don't want to have more levels then 3(0,1,above 2).

Comment: The function you're looking for is `cut()`.

Comment: `factor(replace(d,d>1,2))`

Comment: `cut(d,c(-Inf,0,1,Inf),0:2)`

Comment: What do you intend to do with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should achieve what you asked:

```
library("tidyverse")

c(0,1,0,1,2,3,0,5,6,7,5) %>% 
  as.character() %>% 
  as_factor() %>% 
  fct_other(keep = c("1", "2"))
#>  [1] Other 1     Other 1     2     Other Other Other Other Other Other
#> Levels: 1 2 Other
```

Answer (score 1):

You can limit values with `pmin`:

```
v <- c(0,1,0,1,2,3,0,5,6,7,5)
pmin(v, 2)
# [1] 0 1 0 1 2 2 0 2 2 2 2
```